# How to connect SQL server with CodeIgniter 4 using xampp( PHP 8.0 )

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, xampp

Any steps are there which will guide to make connection between CodeIgniter 4 and SQL Server database.

Complete flow step by step which will easily implement.

Answer (score 0):

I did integrated this requirement some time a go, kindly follow the below steps to successfully integration.

1. Download sqlsrv dll files as per you PHP version from this [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/releases/tag/v5.10.1).
2. Extract the zip file and copy "php_pdo_sqlsrv_80_ts.dll" and "php_sqlsrv_80_ts.dll" files. for more clarification i attached image, kindly go through it.
   [image]
3. Paste these files in the you xampp directory "\xampp\php\ext".
4. Open php.ini file add/enable extensions "php_pdo_sqlsrv_80_ts.dll" and "php_sqlsrv_80_ts.dll" and restart you apache server. For more clarification go through with below image.
   [image]
5. Check in your phpinfo sqlsrv extension is enable or not. for more clarification check below image.
   [image]

6. Modify below mention changes in your database configuration file  "app/Config/Database.php".

```
$default = [
        'DSN'      => '',
        'hostname' => 'hostname/ipaddress',
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => 'password',
        'database' => 'databasename',
        'DBDriver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'DBPrefix' => '',
        'pConnect' => false,
        'port'     => 1433,
];
```

and last you need to initialize database in you controller or model. you can make call as per below code.

```
$db = \Config\Database::connect();
        $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tablename");
        echo "<pre>"; print_r($query->getResult()); die;
```

Finally you will get the result as per your data.

I hope this will help.